# onCompleted is not working?

Tags: android, facebook

This does not appear to connecting and updating the textfield from the Facebook API can anyone see the problem. I had to change the Request.executeMeRequestAsyc to Request.newMeRequest because it has been deprecated. Any help would be appreciated.

**Code snippet**

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                //---make request to the /me api---
                Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(user != null){
                            TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                            welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to call executeAsync on the request explicitly:

```
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            //---make request to the /me api---
            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(user != null){
                        TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                        welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                    }

                }
            }).executeAsync();  // <----- ADD THIS
        }
```